# Does linux ever return regions from `mmap` that are adjacent?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, mmap

Does `linux` ever return regions from `mmap` that are adjacent to previously-allocated regions (in the absence of the available address space filling up)?

I'd like to allocate stacks using `mmap`. It is imperative that a stack overflow should be caught by memory protection. Of course, one can easily force this by setting one page of the `mmap` region to no access, but is this really necessary? Does `linux` every return adjacent regions from `mmap`? It sounds like a pretty bad idea to do that.

Comment: According to the `man mmap` it would seem that it will, more often than not actually. `If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the address at which to create the mapping ... on Linux, the mapping will be created at a nearby page boundary.`

Comment: If it's "imperative" that stack overflow be caught by memory protection, *you have to do that yourself*.  Note that no matter how large you make your overflow guard areas, you will still miss any stack overflow that is bad enough to completely jump over your guard page(s).